# Proper place for image generation in Django model

Tags: django

I need to generate logo if a user does not attach any image to model form.
Where is the best place for such code?

1. `form.clean_logo()`
2. `form.save()`
3. `model.save()`
4. `model.pre_save` signal

And how to not override existing, already saved logo ?

Using a default value is not an option in this instance as the image needs to be auto generated.

Comment: Is this a dynamic image generation or is this a default image?

Comment: @MattWritesCode dynamic, initial data for ImageField isn't an option :)

Comment: Is the image generation a process heavy task? Are you better off doing this as a job or not to worried?

Comment: If the image is directly related to the model (i.e. the auto-generated text relies on another field in the model such as the name) I would create a model method to do this. Then you can easily to `my_object.generate_logo()`. Furthermore you could have an `ImageField` on the model then to get easy access to this newly generated image. How you run that method is up to you: you could dispatch a celery task from the `form.save()` or simply run is synchronously

Comment: I think that logo will be generated synchronously (it's small enough) or just randomly selected one of many pre-generated. 
@TimmyO'Mahony thanks for idea with model's method, as about place for generation, I agree that  form processing is the proper place